# Actions On Google import a existing project

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, actions-builder

I have a existing project in DialogFlow but I need the new Action Builder (Actions on Google) and when I click on manage assistant app, it just go to the older version so it has not got the new action builder.

I don't know what to do :(

Could someone helps me?

This is the older version: (My project)

[image: The older version]

This is the current version of Actions:

[image: The current version]

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to switch your project from Dialogflow to Actions Builder, or start a new project?

Comment: I had a project in DialogFlow but I needed the Actions Builder in order to account linking, so when I clicked in Integrations settings (DialogFlow) to go to Actions Builder, it went to the previous version of actions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I created a new project in Dialogflow, I copied the intents. Then, I created a new project in Actions on Google and in the space of name, I could choose the new project. As a result, I have the new project with the new builder.